# Creating a new object from the fill of an object

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have some shapes that have a white fill with a black 5pt stroke and I need to separate/create a new object that is the same size as the fill. Duplicating the objects and removing the stroke still leaves the objects 2.5pt too big.

A quick solution I have found is to export the objects into photoshop, select the fill by color-range and cutting to new layer, but this isn't really practical as I lose quality and I need to do this potentially hundreds of times.

I was wondering if there was an easier way to do this, preferably in illustrator? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This assumes that strokes are a different color than fills and nothing is a gradient....

- Select Objects
- `Edit > Copy`
- `Object > Hide > Selection` (to hide the originals for a moment)
- `Edit > Paste in Front`
- `Object > Expand` and just click `OK`
- **Pathfinder Panel** -> click the `Merge` button
- Using the Direct Selection Tool (white arrow), select a stroke (which is now actually a shape)
- `Select > Same > Fill Color`
- Hit the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key

You then have objects which are the size of only the fills minus the stroke areas. And they will be in the *exact* same position as the original fills.

- `Object > Show All` to unhide the original objects